# Python dealing with reverse lookup

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 20 strings which match 20 integers. All integers and strings are *unique*. I am considering but would like to avoid creating two dictionaries. One dictionary will be indexed by the string, and one dictionary will be indexed by the integer.

- How should I handle this situation?

I created two lists. One containing strings, the other containing integers. I am thinking of building two functions. One function will produce a string. The other function will  produce an integer. Another alternative is to combine these into one function by branching if produced argument is an integer or a string.

- How is this comparable to a dictionary? Will it consume a lot of cpu?
  (this function will run **millions** of times everyday)
- Should I just create a list of tuples which are (string, int) and then
  create two dictionaries, one mapping int to list position and other
  string to list position? Will it be the **best** way?

I don't have many items so I can sacrifice some memory.

Please explain the best method with an explanation of why it is the best.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your objection to having two dictionaries?  As long as you generate one automatically from the other, rather than defining them independently, it seems like the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @MarkReed, it sounds a bit wrong. I am new to Python and I thought there would be a better way for creating an entity which acts as if reverse lookup on a dictionary. That's all. Do you think that's the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever solution you go with, if you want it to be robust, you should probably wrap a class around it that automatically updates the other direction when you update one. For instance, here's a start at a basic bidirectional dictionary using @mgilson's technique (which means it won't work if there's any overlap between the two sets of items you're mapping to each other; having different types works great, though):

```
class BiDict(dict):
  """Bidirectional Dictionary - setting 'key' to 'value' also
     sets 'value' to 'key' (so don't use overlapping mappings)
  """

  def __init__(self, *args):
    super(BiDict, self).__init__(*args)

    # After regular dict initialization, loop over any items
    # and add their reverse.  Note that we can't use any of the
    # iter* methods here since we're adding items in the body
    # of the loop.
    for key in self.keys():
      super(BiDict, self).__setitem__(self[key], key);


  def __setitem__(self, key, val):
    # If the key has an old value, delete its reverse
    if key in self:
      super(BiDict, self).__delitem__(self[key])

    # Then add both forward and reverse for the new value
    super(BiDict, self).__setitem__(key, val);
    super(BiDict, self).__setitem__(val, key);

  def __delitem__(self, key):
    # delete both directions
    if key in self:
      super(BiDict, self).__delitem__(self[key]);
      super(BiDict, self).__delitem__(key);
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> from bidict import BiDict
>>> d = BiDict({'a':1,'b':2})
>>> d['a']
1
>>> d[2]
'b'
>>> d['c']=3
>>> d[3]
'c'
>>> del d['a']
>>> d['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
>>> d[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 1
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and efforts. I will go like this.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use 1 dictionary which does the mapping both ways?

```
ints = list(range(10))
strs = [str(x) for x in ints]
d = dict(zip(ints,strs))
d.update(zip(strs,ints))

print repr(d[1])   # '1'
print repr(d['1']) # 1
```

Since you have unique strings and unique integers, then the union of those two sets should also be a unique list which contains all the elements from the other two.  There should be no problem holding them both in the dictionary

Comment: Hi @mgilson! I thought of that as I said in my question but as I also explained to @MarkReed above, it didn't seem like an elegant solution for reverse lookup. Do you think it's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @Phil -- I don't think there's anything *wrong* with it.  I think that the actual solution probably depends a lot on what you're actually planning on doing with this mapping.  This will be a lot more computationally efficient compared to using `.index` on a list though.